# Listener libgdx

Tags: разработка-игр, libgdx

Имеется класс наследованный от актера.

Хочу отследить нажатие конкретно по нему.

Добавляю следующее:

```
setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
addListener(new ClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        Gdx.app.log("Actor: ", "is clicked");
     }
});
```

На клик не реагирует, чего не хватает?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас:

1. не определены размеры актера, для листенера это обязательно.
   `actor.setSize(100, 100);` или `actor.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100)`
2. Актер не добавлен в Stage: `Stage.addActor (actor);`
3. Stage не назначен обработчик событий
   `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`